# NGINX cant find assets

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx setup

```
location /forum {
    #rewrite  /forum(.*)  /$1 break;
    alias /home;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

So going into website.com/forum wont work I need to manually type index.php also it wont never load files such as style.css.

Im checking the logs and the path seems to be correct for all requests. All the files are located at /home/forum folder

Comment: try to place try_files $uri $uri/ =404; inside a  location block like i.e. location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is located at `/home/forum/index.php` then `alias` is the wrong directive to use. You should be using `root`.

The `root` directive sets the value of the `$document_root` which is prefixed to the `$uri` to obtain the local pathname.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The `alias` directive is [totally different](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).